# Concat an array of arrays(?) or loop over them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

Mayday! Im tryin to either concat an array of arrays(?) or loop over them, but the problem seem to be how they are nested, any solution on how to concat these or loop over them in one go would be most appreciated!
The main-array has 5 indexes, but every index is an array itself with 20 indexes.

I just found a stack-post about flat() but still I dont get it to wrk...

Some more info here: Im fetching from the tmdb-API that only serves 20 posts so Im loping 5 times to add 100posts to my state. But the result is a messy nested thing that I would like to flattened to one clean array:

```
const fetchLoop = async(page)=> {

const URL = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${type}? 
api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${page}`
const fetchRes = await fetch(URL)
.then(res => res.json())
setLoopPosts(prev => [...prev, fetchRes])

}

[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(page => fetchLoop(page))
```

[image: the array]

Comment: This is an array of **objects**, not an array of arrays. Please post the data as text rather than an image. Also include the code that you are using to loop over the array and describe what happens when you run it and what you want it to do differently.

Comment: The values of the outer array are not arrays, they are objects containing arrays. You can do `data.flatMap(x => x.results)`.

Comment: Yeah but one level down like theArray[0].results should be an array with 20 indexes?
I thought this should work but apperently no: 
const array1 = loopPosts[0].results.flat(infinity)

Comment: @visua Just use a nested `for` loop if you want to `loop` them. `for(let x = 0; x < testing.length; x++) { for(let y = 0; y < testing[x].results.length; y++){ etc.`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added some info to my post now for clarification.

Comment: @FelixKling Fantastic that did the trick exactly what I was looking for! Big ups!
Sorry about the somewhat poor question but stressed out of my eyeballs!

Comment: Thanks for adding some code to show what you are trying. Let's work on simplifying it further so that we can focus on just the question you are asking here. Since you are asking about how to iterate over an array, it doesn't matter that the array comes from a fetch call. So instead, just hardcode an example array with 3 or 4 entries. Then show the code that iterates over that array.

Answer (score 0):

do you have an example of your arrays?

```
myArray = [[1,2],3,[4,5]];

myFlatArray = myArray.flat();

console.log(myFlatArray);
```

expected log result is [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

For flatening arrays, you can use `flatMap` or `flat`.

```js
const data = [
  { page: 1, results: [{ a: 1 }] },
  { page: 2, results: [{ b: 2 }] },
];

// Using flatMap
const res = data.flatMap((item) => item.results);
console.log(res);

// Using flatMap and destructuring
const res2 = data.flatMap(({results}) => results);
console.log(res2);


// Using map, destructuring and flat
const res3 = data.map(({results}) => results).flat();
console.log(res3);
```